# Why doesnt the OS play music files or videos from the USB stick?

Tags: usb, video, music

Okay I know this must seem like a dumb question but I downloaded and ran the OS from a 16 GB USB stick/flashdrive and I love it, but I could not watch videos or listen to music files! And I LOVE those. Am I doing something wrong? I was wondering if it has to do with my running it off this USB thing? Also I can't seem to use that software thing to add anything? I guess I am wondering why not and if it is because it is running off a flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu cannot include support for MP3 or DVD video playback or recording. MP3 formats are patented, and the patent holders have not provided the necessary licenses. Ubuntu also excludes other multimedia software due to patent, copyright, or license restrictions, such as Adobe Flash Player and RealPlayer.

That doesn’t mean you can’t play .mp3 files in Ubuntu, it just takes a bit of work (not much).

First enable the Multiverse repository. To do that open `Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources`. Then click on "`software restricted by copyright (multiverse repository)`". You can also enable all other repositories.

Then in the search panel of the Ubuntu software center type `ubuntu restricted extras` and hit the search button. From the list install `ubuntu restricted extras`.

Now you can play all the things.

**Alternative:**

- Go to `Ubuntu Software Center`.
- Search for `VLC`
- Install the VLC player.