# What do I have load to watch movies, netflix and such?

Tags: installation

what do I have load to watch movies netflix and such.

by other questions posted there may be another site i should ask my question.

got to start somewhere

thanks

jj

Answer (score 0):

For the "and such": Thanks to **maqtanim** for this answer from [Why doesnt the OS play music files or videos from the USB stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370339/why-doesnt-the-os-play-music-files-or-videos-from-the-usb-stick/370353#370353)

Ubuntu cannot include support for MP3 or DVD video playback or recording. MP3 formats are patented, and the patent holders have not provided the necessary licenses. Ubuntu also excludes other multimedia software due to patent, copyright, or license restrictions, such as Adobe Flash Player and RealPlayer.

That doesn’t mean you can’t play .mp3 files in Ubuntu, it just takes a bit of work (not much).

First enable the Multiverse repository. To do that open Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources. Then click on "software restricted by copyright (multiverse repository)". You can also enable all other repositories.

Then in the search panel of the Ubuntu software center type ubuntu restricted extras and hit the search button. From the list install ubuntu restricted extras. Now you can play all the things.